# Handling port already in use error in express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to work on an automated error handling algorithm that will try to restart the service again if the port is already in use.
The technique works as follows:

1. port is already in use error occurs, so the server will emit an event called 'error'.
2. print to the console that "port already in use"
3. try to reconnect to the port `x` times, in between each attempt there is 5 seconds delay.
4. if all possible `x` number of attempts exceeded, reject the promise with a meaningful message.

The output should look the following:

```
Error: port 3000 already in use
Note: trying to restart the service on port 3000... attempts left 4 // 5 seconds later...
Note: trying to restart the service on port 3000... attempts left 3 // 5 seconds later...
Note: trying to restart the service on port 3000... attempts left 2 // 5 seconds later...
Note: trying to restart the service on port 3000... attempts left 1 // 5 seconds later...
Error: Server shutting down because port 3000 already being used by another service.
```

I've been trying, testing, and failing for about **7** hours in total.

1. I've tried my best to make it work
2. I wanted to split the code into multiple units for clean and understandable code.

Here is my code, if you have a better code than this or a modification on this code, everything is acceptable.

## if you find it hard to understand my code, write your own code, no problem, and I'll resolve it and try to apply it to my code.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const listen = (port) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const server = app.listen(port)
        let times = 5
        let duration = 2000
        let left = 5 // attempts left
        let showErrMsg = true
        server.on('listening', () => {
            const message = `Listening on port ${port}...`
            console.log(message)
            resolve(message)
        })
        server.on('error', async (error) => {
            if (error.code === 'EADDRINUSE') {
                left = left - 1
                let message
                if (showErrMsg) {
                    message = (`port ${port} already in use`)
                    console.log(message)
                    showErrMsg = false
                }
                message = `trying to restart the service on port ${port}... attempts left ${left} `
                console.log(message)
                server.close()
                while (left !== 1) {
                    console.log(left)
                    await setTimeout(() => server.listen(port), duration) times ???
                }
                message = `Server is shutting down`
                reject(message)
            }
        })
    })
}
const controller = {
    listen,
    app,
}
module.exports = controller
```

> my listen function is returning a promise because it's being used by another file that requires it to be a promise, so I can use `await` there.

Comment: very interesting.. btw what are the errors(as in what goes wrong) when you try your code?

Comment: It's hard to answer this question <:D, for now, if you tried this code you'll get an infinite loop printing 5.
I was facing other errors, such as `left` is being subtracted by one even under zero, so -5 -6 -7 -8 ...etc forever,
and some other errors. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it will recursively to trigger it on `error` event when you trigger `server.listen` which your port is already used, so you don't need to use while loop, use if condition to do it. And only when condition match the last time, you reject error.

By the way, I changed your condition to `left !== 0`.

```js
server.on('error', (error) => {
    if (error.code === 'EADDRINUSE') {
        left = left - 1
        let message
        if (showErrMsg) {
            message = (`port ${port} already in use`)
            console.log(message)
            showErrMsg = false
        }
        message = `trying to restart the service on port ${port}... attempts left ${left} `
        console.log(message)
        if (left !== 0) {
            console.log(left)
            setTimeout(() => server.listen(port), duration)
        } else {
            message = `Server is shutting down`
            reject(message)
        }
    }
})
```

So, your outside js could use it like this.

```js
const app = require("./app.js")

async function main () {
    try {
        const result = await app.listen(5000)
        console.log("outside result", result)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("outside error");
        console.log(error);
    }
}

main()
```

So, the output look like this.

[image]

And if your port is released by other node process, it will successfully listen like below demo.

[image]

I provide the test code which I used.

```js
// app.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const listen = (port) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let server = app.listen(port)
        let times = 5
        let duration = 2000
        let left = 5 // attempts left
        let showErrMsg = true
        server.on('listening', () => {
            const message = `Listening on port ${port}...`
            console.log(message)
            resolve(message)
        })
        server.on('error', (error) => {
            if (error.code === 'EADDRINUSE') {
                left = left - 1
                let message
                if (showErrMsg) {
                    message = (`port ${port} already in use`)
                    console.log(message)
                    showErrMsg = false
                }
                message = `trying to restart the service on port ${port}... attempts left ${left} `
                console.log(message)
                if (left !== 0) {
                    console.log(left)
                    setTimeout(() => server.listen(port), duration)
                } else {
                    message = `Server is shutting down`
                    reject(message)
                }
            }
        })
    })
}
const controller = {
    listen,
    app,
}
module.exports = controller
```

```js
// d.js
const app = require("./app.js")

async function main () {
    try {
        const result = await app.listen(5000)
        console.log("outside result", result)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("outside error");
        console.log(error);
    }
}

main()
```